# GXT 3 GridRowEditing SimpleComboBox entries not displayed

Tags: gwt, combobox, gxt

i'm currently using a GXT3 grid to display data from a custom object EntityDAO.
This class contains 3 attributes: an id and two references to complex type objects
Let's call them

```
Long id;
UserInfo userInfo;     
OutputInfo outputInfo;
```

I created an interface to explicit the desired display of these info:

```
interface EntityDAOProperties extends PropertyAccess<EntityDAO> {
    ModelKeyProvider<EntityDAO> id();
    @Path("userInfo.name")
    ValueProvider<EntityDAO, String> step();
    @Path("outputInfo.name")
    ValueProvider<EntityDAO, String> outputInfo();
}
```

The display is perfectly fine. The matter is that i want to be able to add/edit rows to my grid.

To do so, I have a

```
GridRowEditing<EntityDAO> editing = createGridEditing(grid);
```

comprising a

```
SimpleComboBox<String> comboUser = new SimpleComboBox<String>(new LabelProvider<String>() {
    @Override
    public String getLabel(String item) {
        return item;
    }
});

for(...){
    comboUser.add("entry " + i); // For instance
    logger.info("entry : " +i); // For instance
    i++;
}
comboUser.setEditable(false);
comboUser.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
```

When i double click on my line and make the GridRowEditing appear, the combo doesn't seem to have more than 1 row and the click on the expand arrow doesn't change anything to the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the part where you set the property editor for the combobox, here is the example code:

```
  SimpleComboBox<Light> combo = new SimpleComboBox<Light>(new StringLabelProvider<Light>());
  combo.setClearValueOnParseError(false);
  combo.setPropertyEditor(new PropertyEditor<Light>() {

    @Override
    public Light parse(CharSequence text) throws ParseException {
      return Light.parseString(text.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Light object) {
      return object == null ? Light.SUNNY.toString() : object.toString();
    }
  });
  combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
  combo.add(Light.SUNNY);
  combo.add(Light.MOSTLYSUNNY);
  combo.add(Light.SUNORSHADE);
  combo.add(Light.MOSTLYSHADY);
  combo.add(Light.SHADE);
  // combo.setForceSelection(true);
  editing.addEditor(cc2, new Converter<String, Light>() {

    @Override
    public String convertFieldValue(Light object) {
      return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Light convertModelValue(String object) {
      try {
        return Light.parseString(object);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
      }

    }

  }, combo);
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't solve the problem.